# How do I show only those entries beginning with A, B, C, etc.?

Tags: expressionengine

I have an Expression Engine site with several hundred entries. The client wants the option to display entries based on the first letter of the entry title.

So for example the following page http://www.mysite.com/a/ would only display entries that begin with the letter A and so forth.

Is there a way to do this in the channel tag? If so, how is it done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want the [Low Alphabet add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-alphabet/) for that.